# XNA Audio and WASAPI conflict?

Tags: windows-phone-8, xna, wasapi

I've recently been working on integrating some code for a VoIP application. On one end, the UI (mainly the dialer) uses the XNA Audio framework to play sound bytes (DTMF) on button presses. On the other hand, the actual call module uses WASAPI for capturing/rendering audio. After integrating the parts, I was seeing an AUDCLIENT_BUFFER_SILENT flag during the call, and no audio was getting through. I disabled all traces of XNA and tried again, only to see the call work just fine (no silent buffer flag present).

Do XNA and WASAPI not play nice? Is there a way to keep using XNA for the sound bytes and WASAPI for calls?

Comment: The only XNA calls are for creating a SoundEffectInstance and then playing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to tie things up here -- Microsoft has stated that while XNA is still available on WP8, it has been officially deprecated. So, assuming the problem stems from cross API headbutting, the answer is to use another API. I found that using MediaElements is a suitable replacement for the XNA sound effects.